# Meteor/node, prepending date/time on server-side output

Tags: node.js, meteor

When doing `meteor run` on localhost, all server-side output (including errors and `console.log` messages) output the date/time before every log line.

However when running `node bundle/main.js` from built Meteor code, server-side output does not write the date/time.

Is there an easy way to instruct `node` to output the date/time on every server-side line like `meteor run` does?

Ps- I am referring to the console on the *server*, not the *client*.

Comment: you could use a logger to your whole project it will give you that, as far for quick fix I'm not really sure